# What is the name of these little plastic things that protect wires from being cut into by the sharp edges of a drilled hole?

Tags: identification, wiring, terminology

What is the name of these little plastic things that protect wires from being cut into by the sharp edges of a drilled hole?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In addition to all the good answers: if you are looking to purchase a grommet/bushing specifically for preventing someone damaging internal parts by pulling on the cable, you'll want to do a search for *stress relief* or *strain relief* bushing.

Comment: Any way to put the comprehensive answer into the FAQ listing?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

### Summary:

*I've been doing a lot of research on this and found several excellent definitions from [CableOrganizer](https://www.cableorganizer.com) that has helped to clarify a lot of the confusion I've been having. I'll lay this out as clearly as I can to cite the differences between grommets and bushings which has made it easier to find the correct part I was looking for.*

---

### Is it a grommet or a bushing?

The terms "grommet" and "bushing" are pretty open in terms of their meaning, and depending on their application, but typically both words refer to a piece of material, usually circular in shape, that provides a buffer between two areas that can serve many different purposes, from insulation to vibration resistance to protection from abrasion and friction.<sup>[1](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommets/)</sup>

A *grommet* is basically just a [rubber bumper](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommet/) that protects cables from the hard edges or sharp corners of whatever surface it may be passing between.

[image]

### What's is the purpose of grommets and bushings?

When running your cables through small openings or around sharp curves you will encounter rough metal or wooden edges that may damage or break your cables. These rubber grommets provide an abrasion resistant cushion around these small openings and sharp edges to protect your wiring.

A *bushing* is similar to a grommet and serves the function, to protect a cable from damage, but are notably more complex. These additional features can provide extra protection and functionality beyond a simple rubber pass-though.<sup>[2](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommet/)</sup>

### Examples of common bushings

- ***PVC Bushings***

  Other bushings are a bit more complex in their design. Rather than a simple rubber circle, many bushings have different features that help give a little extra protection or added functionality. [Non-metallic wire bushings](https://www.cableorganizer.com/arlington-industries/wire-bushings/), for example, are essentially similar to rubber grommets, though they're made from PVC and feature a threaded pattern that allows them to install into surfaces more securely.<sup>[1](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommets/)</sup>

[image]

- ***Snap Bushings***

  [Snap bushings](https://www.cableorganizer.com/richco/closed-snap-in-bushing.htm) are so called because they can snap into the surface and lock into place once installed, thanks to the design of the outer edge that allows portions to expand once placed into the desired hole.

  Many snap bushings are simple circular pass-throughs, but [others](https://www.cableorganizer.com/richco/snap-bushing.htm) feature "wings" or "shutters" which are flaps that help keep cables from being too loose in the pass-through, keeping them centered and also protecting them from too much vibration and shock.<sup>[1](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommets/)</sup>

[image]

- ***Snub Bushings***

  Taking it a step further are [snub bushings](https://www.cableorganizer.com/richco/snub-bushing.htm), which have a thick split opening that will close around a cable once it's snapped into place, securing it and ensuring that it doesn't move. While this provides solid insulation and retention, it also means only a single cable can be properly secured in each bushing, rather than a bundle.<sup>[1](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommets/)</sup>

[image]

- ***Open Bushings***

  An [open bushing](https://www.cableorganizer.com/richco/open-snap-in-bushing.htm) is a grommet that is not a closed circle, but rather contains a slit that divides the circle when not installed. This allows it to do a few things closed grommets and bushings can't. Cables can be installed with a side-entry method, instead of a feed-through, for example. Additionally, they can be installed into pre-existing holes, or along pre-existing cable runs.<sup>[1](https://www.cableorganizer.com/grommets/)</sup>

[image]

Steve also mentioned grommet strips, also sometimes referred to as "edging", and can be found with or without adhesive.

[image]

[image]

---

**What is the identity of the part in the question?**

The bushing from my original question ended up being a Heyco snap bushing SB 375-4 (part no. 2030) with an inside diameter of 0.27" (6.8mm). A [complete catalog](https://www.heyco.com/Hole_Plugs/pdf/Snap-Bushings-1.pdf) is available online and parts can be sourced from [Mouser Electronics](https://www.mouser.com/).

Note that an inside diameter of 0.27" is an imperial variation with the next closest metric diameter being 7mm which may have a different outter diameter.

Comment: Good information here.  In plumbing, the term "bushing" is used to refer to a pipe fitting that reduces the size of another female pipe fitting.  In PVC they come in threaded and solvent welded versions, and in metal pipe they are threaded only.

Comment: I've only ever heard these called bushings, not grommets, so thanks for making the connection for me.

Comment: Would you also like to include cable glands?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_gland

Comment: duuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuude I was never able to find any "grommet strips" because I would have never thought they were called that.  Now that I don't need them, of course I find out what they are called! SMH

Comment: That PVC bushing of yours is not used like ordinary bushings. It's an inverse spacer, making the hole for the cable gland smaller. That's why it's tapped inside and out.

Comment: You've missed an important type of grommet - the grooved grommet. This is commonly used in the situation you show. https://5.imimg.com/data5/XK/HN/MY-41191648/rubber-groove-grommet-500x500.jpg

Answer (score 192):

That's a grommet, not to be confused with Gromit.

[image]

*Gromit, of [Wallace and Gromit](https://wallaceandgromit.com/gallery/wallace-and-grommit-1) fame.*

Comment: made my day  :-)

Comment: Got our "funny" head on today? plus 1... :)

Comment: Check the datasheet before buying them though, some are compatible with Wensleydale, some are not.

Comment: this has to be one of the most versatile technical terms ever. I counted > 30 different meanings (interdisciplinary, not limited to EE) when translating to German only: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/grommet

Comment: @dlatikay I only know of one meaning for the word "grommet": it's a thing placed around the inside of a hole, which protects the hole, or something passing through the hole, from wear. What else does it mean?

Comment: lug, loop, bail, sling, washer, disc, thimble, spout, beak, ... :)

Comment: . . . claymation dog character

Comment: @dlatikay - no.  Grommet does *not* mean washer, disc, thimble etc.  There may be 30 German words whose meaning overlaps with "grommet", but that does not mean that the English technical term has more than one meaning.

Comment: I just googled "grommit strip" hoping for an amusing picture to add here.  Sadly due to people's incompetence, all I could find was "grommet strip" spelled incorrectly.  Ho hum.

Comment: Dozens of upvotes because a "lol so funny" picture, compared to the excellent technical answer with lots of examples which are actually _relevant_.

Comment: @pipe - are you worried that OP is going to fit a claymation dog to an electrical appliance? I can hear the voice of Peter Sallis now - "It's the wrong grommet, Grommit! The wrong grommet!"

Comment: @JohnU I'm worried that silly images is pushing back better answers.

Comment: @pipe this is not a silly picture, it helps memorising the word. It really supports the answer.

Comment: @pipe I only see 1 answer that doesn't mention grommet, and it's about as long as this one. I see another that says it's a grommet, and it's very short. The last one, which is by the OP, goes into some long-winded discussion about whether or not it should be called a grommet or bushing. This answer is to-the-point and even gives a funny way to remember the name.

Comment: @rexkogitans I joined this stack just to upvote this answer, for the reason you mentioned

Answer (score 29):

They are called grommets. You can also get grommet strip.

Answer (score 26):

Everyone's already identified basic grommets but I would add that, in the example of mains cable, there are specifically designed (and often legally required) **cable grips** which not only prevent chafing but also prevent the cable being pulled through.

These are significantly different to general-purpose grommets so it's worth knowing the difference and why you might use one or the other.

*Edit:* By request, [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/cable-separators-bushing/1361750/) is an example of a common form of cable grip/gland used to retain fixed mains cables in many appliances:

[image]

RS-Components Stock No. 136-1750

Comment: Can you provide an example image of cable grips?

Comment: Yes - updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

They're called "Strain Relief Bushings"

[Strain Relief Bushing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVvHv.png)

Comment: I don't think they are because Strain Relief Bushings grip the cord to prevent strain on the connections. The OP refers to a device to prevent chafing. The original photo shows a device that clearly does not grip the cord.